# Polynomial approximations to roots of polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, soft-question, exponential-function

Let us assume we want to investigate a family of functions $$R(x) = \sqrt[k]{Q(x)}$$
Where $Q(x)$ is polynomial. We want to to approximate $R(x)$ with polynomial: $R(x) \approx P(x)$

In other words $P(x)$ ("nearly" in some sense) solves the equation $P(x)^k = Q(x)$ for a set of $x$ and a polynomial $Q(x)$ with the extra requirement that $P(x)$ needs be a polynomial.

What would be useful approaches for this problem?

**Own work**: I used a matrix representation of polynomials together with matrix logarithms to calculate $${\bf M_P} = \exp\left(\frac{\log({\bf M_R})}{k}\right)$$
And it turns out to also become a matrix representation for a polynomial.

Just to show that it can give sensible results: on the function $R(x) = \sqrt{(1+2x)^2} = \left|1+2x\right|$ :

[image]

Comment: Have you considered taking roots in a power series ring?